# Python: "list index out of range" when attempting to do a loop that chooses random numbers

Tags: python, loops, indexing

My task is to randomize cards with a name and four categories, and to bring them out from a text file and save the completed cards back to another text file. The number of cards randomized is up to user input, except it will only loop a few times before displaying this error.

```
  line 35, in <module>
  exercise = lines5[exerlinenum]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is the code I am using.

```
x = 0
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
user = int(input("Please enter your even number: "))
if user % 2 == 0:
     answer = list.index(user)
     split_list = list[0:answer+1]
     loop = len(split_list)

else:
     print("Input not even!")
     import random
     while x < loop:

         file = open("dognames.txt", "r")
         lines1=file.readlines()
         namelinenum=random.randint(0, 17)
         dogname = lines1[namelinenum]
         print("Name:", dogname)

         file2 = open("friendliness.txt", "r")
         lines2=file2.readlines()
         frenlinenum=random.randint(0, 10)
         friendliness = lines2[frenlinenum]
         print("Friendliness:", friendliness)

         file4 = open("intelligence.txt", "r")
         lines4=file4.readlines()
         intlinenum=random.randint(0, 100)
         intelligence = lines4[intlinenum]
         print("Intelligence:", intelligence)

         file5 = open("exercise.txt", "r")
         lines5=file5.readlines()
         exerlinenum=random.randint(0, 5)
         exercise = lines5[exerlinenum]
         print("Exercise:", exercise)

         file6 = open("drool.txt", "r")
         lines6=file6.readlines()
         droollinenum=random.randint(0, 10)
         drool = lines6[droollinenum]
         print("Drool:", drool)

         doginfo=(dogname, friendliness, intelligence, exercise, drool)
         file3 = open("dogs.txt", "a")
         file3.write(repr(doginfo))



         x += 1

    file3.close()
```

And here are the text files in question, if that helps.

dognames.txt

```
 Jack
 Harry
 Lyla
 Lucky
 Ringo
 Sadie
 Pinkie
 Teddy
 Simrin
 Andie
 Willow
 Luna
 Bailey
 Zoey
 Checkers
 Cheddar
 Arlo
 Humphrey
```

friendliness.txt

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

intelligence.txt

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11 
12 
13 
14 
15 
16 
17 
18 
19 
20 
21 
22 
23 
24 
25 
26 
27 
28 
29 
30 
31 
32 
33 
34 
35 
36 
37 
38 
39 
40 
41 
42 
43 
44 
45 
46 
47 
48 
49 
50 
51 
52 
53 
54 
55 
56 
57 
58 
59 
60 
61 
62 
63 
64 
65 
66 
67 
68 
69 
70 
71 
72 
73 
74 
75 
76 
77 
78 
79 
80 
81 
82 
83 
84 
85 
86 
87 
88 
89 
90 
91 
92
93
94 
95
96
97 
98
99
100
```

exercise.txt

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

drool.txt

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Thanks a lot, and please go easy on me. I'm a beginner.

Comment: What's the point of generating a random number n in order to read the nth line of a text file, which contains only the number n? The logic of this is not clear to me.

Comment: if you want to learn how to write more idiomatic python post it https://codereview.stackexchange.com, there is a lot you can do better and I'm sure people there will give you a nice explanation

Comment: @chris - not until it's working correctly.  [codereview.se] doesn't like to be presented with known-broken code.

Comment: @TobySpeight if it wasn't obvious this was separate and assuming he listened to the answers below first

Answer (score 2):

The function `random.randint(a,b)` returns a random number inclusive of both `a` and `b`. So in your case, it can return a random number between 0 and 5.

In python and most of the languages, the list indexes start from 0. So your `lines5` list size is 5, having indexes from 0 to 4. Please change line 35 to this -

```
exerlinenum=random.randint(0, 4)
```

And it should work without any issue.
You also need to reduce the second argument by 1 of all `random.randint()` calls so that you don't see this error.

Comment: It seems that the same problem are on all the other lists, but since they are bigger you have less chance to get the error

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if `exerlinenum=random.randint(0, 5)` is `5`, then the index is out of range since the `exercise.txt` just has 5 entries. (Remember, python starts counting indexes with `0`)

Looking at your other lines you have the same problem. (e.g. intelligence does not have 101 entries but only 100.) You most probably only see it with exercise since the probability of getting 5 out of 6 is bigger than getting a 100 out of 101 possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access on element of a list called `lines5`. This list contains 5 elements that are read from `exercise.txt`.

In python, counting starts at 0, so if you want to access the first element of a list, you use `lines5[0]`. If you extend this logic, you will see that `lines5[4]` gives you the 5th element of `lines5`, and `lines5[5]` would try to access the 6th element, which does not exist in your list.

Then, your code example uses `random.randint(0, 5)` to pick a random number. This random number is used to access an element of `lines5`. `random.randint(0, 5)` may return 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5! If it happens to return a 5, you will be hit with

> IndexError: list index out of range

because `lines5` only contains 5 elements, and you are trying to access the 6th element!

You can **solve your problem** by using `random.randint(0, 4)` are adding an additional line to `exercise.txt`

Answer (score 0):

The other answer tells the reason why you get the error - due to the random library function return values. More generic, to get rid of the "list index out of range" error, it is safe to check the index before accessing the list item. For instance,

```
if line5: # make sure the list is not empty
    if exerlinenum >= len(line5): # index out of range
        # throw error or what ever
    else:
        exercise = lines5[exerlinenum]
```